# Display latest post in category

Tags: php, wordpress

Whilst wordpress stack could answer this, I think my problem is more to do with basic PHP logic rather than a wordpress issue.

My problem is that my code is displaying **every** post from a category instead of just the **latest** post. My code must be saying something like foreach post in this category display post, but what I'd like it to say is, **only display the latest post**.

```
$post_type = 'post';

$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

      $args = array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'term' => $term->slug, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'modified','category' => $str );

        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
              if(has_term('double portrait','twin')) {
                 get_post( &$post, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw' )
            }
        endwhile; endif;

    endforeach;

endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Here's the code I have at the moment. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $args = array(
'numberposts' => 10,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 0,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output = ARRAY_A );
```

This will give you 10 recent posts. You can play around with $args array for different results that suits you.

Comment: Isn't numberposts deprecated?

Comment: "numberposts" might be depricated(as i dont have that information) but it works perfect. There must be an alternative provided by WP team :)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way, and without much change, you can break the while after the first iteration, ie:

`if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
              if(has_term('double portrait','twin')) {
                 get_post( &$post, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw' );
                 break;
            }
        endwhile; endif;`

You may consider using this function too: `<?php wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output ) ?>`

There's more info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give that a go and report back :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'category_name' => $str,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'twin',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('double portrait','landscape')
          )
        )
      );
      $myPosts = get_posts($args);
      foreach ( $myPosts as $post ) :
      setup_postdata( $post ); 
      echo get_template_part( 'twin-feature' ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```